# Internal Server Error in Production, but not in Local, and not on "/" route

Tags: .htaccess, slim, production, http-status-code-500

A Slim (PHP microframework) app was developed. It works in localhost, but gets an error 500 in production. Here are the details:

- It's fully working in local.
- In production, the home route ("/") works, but all other routes throw an error 500.
- If any specific route is put in the "/" route, it works.
- The Slim site is hosted in a subdomain. A Wordpress site is hosted on the main domain.
- It is hosted on a shared hosting by 1and1.
- The exact error is:

> Internal Server Error : The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration. Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was
>   encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the
>   request.

- Several htaccess files were tried unsuccessfully.

Thank for your ideas to manage the issue!

Comment: How did you reproduce the error? What does *part of the error* mean?

Comment: @Nima I'm not 100% sure, but I think the error was reproduced when trying another .htaccess file.
_At least part of the error_ means that I had the same "internal server error 500", but maybe it was only part of the error, and maybe it had nothing to do with the error I have in production, who knows ?

Comment: If your Slim app is inside a sub-folder of a defined virtual, or even default, host, you need to use `RewriteBase` to tell `mod_rewrite` how to treat relative paths during rewrites. For starters add `RewriteBase /slim_app` (change `slim_app` to the name of your subfolder) at the very top of your rewrite rules (but after `RewriteEngine on`). If that doesn't work increase your `LogLevel` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) sensitivity to at least `trace6` for `rewrite` (`LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`) and see what the logs spit out.

Comment: @brezanac I did `RewriteBase /MyProjectName` and `RewriteBase /MyProjectName/web` (if in the Server folder there is `Server/TheWordpressSite` and `Server/MyProjectName`). Route / works, and others don't – in prod and in local.

Comment: @Blaised'Estais Rewrites can be deeply influenced by differences in server setups which is why I'd suggest again to skip guessing and go straight for the logs. Simply raise the log level to at least `trace6` for `rewrite` and check what exactly is happening during the whole process (every single step will be recorded). Do note though, `trace6` will write a LOT of data so it's highly advisable to just use it for the main page to catch a trace and then revert it to standard value until you analyze the log.

Comment: @brezanac okay, I just found how to change it. It's in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one, it was working for an old project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Activate this if you need to follow symlinks
    #Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controller
    RewriteRule ^index.php - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you @MinDBreak, it worked ! ! ! (PS: i upvoted u, but SOF doesn't displays it 'till I have 15 points... :)

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this `.htaccess` file instead?

```
# Redirect to front controller
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Does your Apache `DocumentRoot` points to the `web/` folder? [More details](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2)

Comment: Yes, the `DocumentRoot` was defined in the server as `path/to/web`. But I just read : 
To enable the rewrite modul, run:
`sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod actions`
If you plan on using `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` files, you also need to enable the use of `.htaccess` files by changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. But since it's a shared host, I may not have these rights, so maybe that's why ...